# BTRFS transid failure

Tags: btrfs

I can't mount my BTRFS volume anymore.

It says:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0p1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

dmesg | grep BTRFS
    [    2.596762] BTRFS: device label DATA devid 1 transid 311913 /dev/md0p1
    [   98.707993] BTRFS warning (device md0p1): 'recovery' is deprecated, use 'usebackuproot' instead
    [   98.707995] BTRFS info (device md0p1): trying to use backup root at mount time
    [   98.707997] BTRFS info (device md0p1): disabling disk space caching
    [   98.707998] BTRFS info (device md0p1): has skinny extents
    [   98.915571] BTRFS error (device md0p1): parent transid verify failed on 29458432 wanted 5 found 311913
    [   98.937552] BTRFS error (device md0p1): parent transid verify failed on 29458432 wanted 5 found 311913
    [   98.990667] BTRFS error (device md0p1): open_ctree failed

dmesg | grep transid
    [    2.596762] BTRFS: device label DATA devid 1 transid 311913 /dev/md0p1
    [   98.915571] BTRFS error (device md0p1): parent transid verify failed on 29458432 wanted 5 found 311913
    [   98.937552] BTRFS error (device md0p1): parent transid verify failed on 29458432 wanted 5 found 311913
```

I tried `btrfs-zero-log` but it doesn't help.
I don't know what to do. I didn't found any useful article on the Internet.

Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be part of the parity raid (5/6) Gotchas, see [THIS](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Affecting_all_versions) link:

```
Parity RAID

Currently raid5 and raid6 profiles have flaws that make it strongly not recommended as per the Status page.
    {..}
    If a crash happens while a raid5/raid6 volume is being written this can result in a "transid" mismatch as in transid verify failed.
    The resulting corruption cannot be currently fixed.
```

In which case there is no way to repair the damage done to your Raid.
Did you use BTRFS Raid 5/6 ?

According to [THIS](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/btrfs-drive-fails-to-mount-suddenly/25085) link, it might still be possible to restore the data using:

`sudo btrfs restore -sxmSv /dev/md0p1 ~/Backup/`

For a list of all options, use 'btrfs restore --help'

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you edit your answer to include the essential information from the link you provided? Thanks!